# How to click on p element with property

Tags: puppeteer, headless-browser

Im trying to click on the first element that look like this:

```
<div>
 <div class="report-name" data-qa="x1x">
  <div tabindex="0" class="af-core keyboard-navigation-element gray-link"><a class="af-core link-with-arrow right " target="_blank">boxes</a></div>
 </div>
 <div class="report-name" data-qa="x2x">
  <div tabindex="0" class="af-core keyboard-navigation-element gray-link"><a class="af-core link-with-arrow right " target="_blank">bags</a> </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

i tried this 2 lines of code:

```
await page.click('div[data-qa="x1x"]');
await page.$x("//a[contains(text(), 'boxes')]");
```

but I cannot click on it.

Comment: What does "I cannot click on it" means? What is the error?

Comment: @pavelsaman , its a link and i want to open it, im taking picture of the screen after the click event.

Comment: Maybe try `await page.click('div[data-qa="x1x"] a');` if you want to click on a *link*?

Comment: @Vaviloff yes that was it, thanks you man :)